Ansible API for jobs in a workflow
I could see that the below API is used to get the output of a job template in Ansible.
/api/v2/jobs/{id}/stdout/
I have three job templates, which is part of a Workflow template.
I have only the workflow job ID. Is there an API to find the IDs of the three jobs that was run as part of the workflow job?

Parts of a possible answer can be found under Retriving a Workflow Job
